# Trying to extract SSL client certificate from android app

Tags: tls, certificates, android, burp-suite, certificate-pinning

I'm trying to find out a specific request from an android application to its API server. Using Burp Suite, I get a handshake failure alert. Using fiddler it asks me to provide a custom certificate.

[image: fiddler pop up]

Now I have used apktool to de-compile the application, and I have found these files:

- arsalan-ha.quizofkings.com.pem
- certificate.crt
- private_key.pfx
- root-ca.crt
- x1.pfx

But they don't look like certificates. They are secrets used to generate certificates most likely, if I'm correct.

I've uploaded the files [here](https://gofile.io/?c=6e62wE)

Could I use these secrets (if they are), to generate certificates and try one by one?

Comment: Why do you think those certificate files are not certificates?

Comment: @schroeder passing them to Burp gives error of invalid length, also their contents are not what I have seen as an ssl certificate.

Comment: They are encoded ...

Comment: @schroeder are there any tools to help me find out the encryption algorithm?

Comment: I said "encoded" not "encrypted"

Comment: Sorry, tools to help me decode them

Comment: Read the answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to extract the certificate and password with the help of running Frida server on a rooted Android >= 4.2 device and then running a script after attaching to the application.

Here's the link to the related script tutorial:
http://ceres-c.it/frida-android-keystore/

**Note:**

There was no need to use keytool to re-generate the certificate mentioned at the end of the article. Because it was a **PKCS12** certificate and enough to import in Burp's Client SSL Certificates.

After that the application's server accepted the requests.

Hope it helps others.

Comment: thanks for the script, managed to get a client cert from an app i was debugging! The link doesn’t seem to work anymore, the full url now is https://ceres-c.it/2018/12/16/frida-android-keystore/

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a good excuse for you to read up on certificate file formats, and spend some time with openssl or another cert viewer (personally I like KeyStore Explorer) until you figure out what format those files are in, and what format Burp is expecting.

For a client cert, usually Burp wants the certificate + matching private key bundled together into a single `.p12` file. I'm not going to download your files because security, but my guess is that you will need to combine `certificate.crt` + `private_key.pfx` into a single `.p12` file using openssl / KeyStore Explorer. If `private_key.pfx` is a password-protected file, then you may need to do some more reverse-engineering of the application binary to find that password.

Comment: Thanks for the details, file contents are much alike as of format. This is what "certificate.crt" has for example: https://i.ibb.co/7SyVm54/cer.png
What tools would help me reverse-engineer more? Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: These are binary files, not text files, so Notepad won't know how to render it. As I said above, my favourite tool for working with certificate files is [KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/). The openssl command-line util is also a good choice

Comment: I asked a question here to explain the difference between certificates and private keys: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/226747/61443